# Click an image to open a slideshow with static text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a website with a portfolio, and would like to be able to click on a single image for each project, which would then dim the page, and open a slideshow with multiple images of the project, as well as a description.  Basically this would be a lightbox, but instead of just opening the single image, each different lightbox would contain a slideshow on the left, and static text on the right.  Is this possible?  I thought maybe it would be done by implementing something with http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/

Thanks so much for your help, you guys are amazing!

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening up a single image using the default implementation:

```
<span data-featherlight="myimage.png">Open image in lightbox</a>
```

You could try instead to use FeatherLight's iFrame feature and call an external Div:

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
<div id="mylightbox"><img src="myimage.jpg" /><p>This div will be opened in a lightbox</p></div>
```

You could then style this to have the image float left, the text float right etc.

Unsure as to whether this will work with FeatherLight's gallery extension though!

Comment: That sounds very close to what I want, but won't there need to be a specific image in that case?  Would I remove the img src tag?

Also, how would I do this if I wanted multiple different lightboxes?  As they all have the same div id, wouldn't they all be identical?

Is there another method/program more suited to this?

Comment: @user3888851 Depends, are you using a CMS or is this a flat HTML site? If it's flat, using specific ID's shouldn't a problem. I can't comment on how wise it is to embed a slideshow within a popup window (might be a bit confusing for a user?) but it's possible using FeatherLight's iFrame feature. You could combine it with something like [owlslider](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) to ensure it's fully responsive.

Comment: Flat HTML.  Thanks for the advice, and I think you're right.  I'll probably just have it go to a whole new page and THEN have the slideshow, etc.  Right now I'm just having an insane amount of trouble with the script.  If you could figure out what the heck is going on you'd be my hero: http://colin-ratcliff.com/cb500.html

Everything has been working great, but the slider isn't working with my site for some reason.